# Rails update inside model ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to make update inside my model

```
    self => BookingService(id: integer, currency_code: string, total_price: integer, group_total: integer, other attrs)
```

but when i  made `update(total_price:1,group_total:1)` i have got

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)


[37] pry(BookingService)> update(total_price:1,group_total:1)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
from /Users/xx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@air_api/gems/activerecord-4.1.13/lib/active_record/relation.rb:352:in `update'

[38] pry(BookingService)> self.update(total_price:1,group_total:1)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
from /Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@air_api/gems/activerecord-4.1.13/lib/active_record/relation.rb:352:in `update'
```

Why it have happened?

Comment: What is `self` here ? Add your code to show how you are calling model method to update attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the source code for the `update` method:

```
def update(id, attributes)
  if id.is_a?(Array)
    idx = -1
    id.collect { |one_id| idx += 1; update(one_id, attributes[idx]) }
  else
    object = find(id)
    object.update_attributes(attributes)
    object
  end
end
```

As you can see, the method is expecting a reference to the record.

Try doing this instead:

```
self.update(...)
```

The reference to `self` should solve your issue.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update/class

## Edit

OP tried the solution and it still didn't work, probably because his method is a `ClassMethod`.

Try this instead:

```
update(id, {attr})
```

Comment: `self` didn't help

Comment: it works with `id`, tnx. But i need to investigate what have caused the problem.

Comment: @user it depends on where you call the code. `update` as an instance method `BookingService.new.update()` doesn't require you to pass an id, however a class method `update` `BookingService.update() ` does

Comment: @NikitaMisharin exactly, so `self` wasn't working because the method calling `update` was a `ClassMethod`? Could you show us you're code @user?

Comment: You were close, you need to pass the id of the objects you want to update, either as an integer or as an array. `BookingService.update([id's], {attributes}]`